# How to track the login details in SQL Server who deleted the data

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-administration, sql-delete

I came across a weird situation in SQL Server db. I see few developer are randomly deleting/updating the data over multiple tables. Is there any mechanism exits in SQL Server to capture all information like who deleted the records or who updated the records ext?

Details:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> 
         (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve these kind of data from the transaction log (`fn_dblog`).

Just note recovery model of the database (`simple` or `full`) defines how long your transactions may stick in your log file.

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname
SET @TableName = 'schema.tableName' -- Make sure to include schema e.g: dbo.tableName

SELECT su.[name] AS UserName
       ,CASE logs.Operation
           WHEN 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS' THEN 'Deleted'
           WHEN 'LOP_MODIFY_ROW' THEN 'Updated'
       END AS [Transaction Type]
    ,fl.[Begin Time] AS [Transaction Begin]
FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) AS fl
INNER JOIN (SELECT  [Transaction ID]
                    ,Operation
            FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
            WHERE AllocUnitName LIKE @TableName + '%'
            AND (Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS' OR Operation = 'LOP_MODIFY_ROW')
            ) AS logs ON logs.[Transaction ID] = fl.[Transaction ID]
INNER JOIN sysusers AS su ON su.[sid] = fl.[Transaction SID]
```

You can easily expand this query to include all your tables

Comment: Thanks for query, Our db is  in simple recovery model. I cannot track the changes made over the table using the above query. Is there any other ways to track the information?

Comment: You can still use this query but for short period of time. The other way of doing this is make triggers and run them after your insert or update and store the result in an audit table.